# Datagrid not dynamically updating with the changes on the table created with the SELECT statement

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I created a table using the select statement as written below:

```sql
CREATE TABLE TOURGUIDE AS SELECT STAFF_ID, STAFF_NAME, STAFF_CONTACT_NO, STAFF_ADDRESS, STAFF_GENDER FROM STAFF WHERE DES_ID=101;
```

DES_ID is the designation ID which I reference as a foreign key in the STAFF table from the DESIGNATION table.

I display the columns from TOURGUIDE table in a data grid view with the following query,

```sql
SELECT * FROM "TOURGUIDE" ORDER BY "STAFF_ID"
```

It displays all the extracted details of the staff that matches the given DES_ID. Also, I have altered the TOURGUIDE table to add few more columns

```sql
SQL> ALTER TABLE TOURGUIDE ADD LICENSE_STATUS VARCHAR(10 CHAR);

Table altered.

SQL> ALTER TABLE TOURGUIDE ADD LICENSE_NUMBER VARCHAR(10 CHAR);

Table altered.

SQL> ALTER TABLE TOURGUIDE ADD LICENSED_ISSUED_DATE VARCHAR(10 CHAR);

Table altered.
```

However, when I insert few more values on STAFF table with the DES_ID=101 it will not update the changes in the data grid view.

So how can I dynamically update the changes on the STAFF table to the datagrid?

Note: I tried with creating the TOURGUIDE view instead of table but since I need to add more columns on Tourguide table by altering it. How can I achieve that?

Comment: You need to create a VIEW, not a TABLE. See https://www.oracletutorial.com/oracle-view/oracle-create-view/.

Comment: @TheImpaler How do I alter the VIEW table again to add the column other that from the staff table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a VIEW, not a TABLE. See [Oracle CREATE VIEW](http://oracletutorial.com/oracle-view/oracle-create-view).

For example:

```
CREATE VIEW TOURGUIDE AS 
  SELECT STAFF_ID, STAFF_NAME, STAFF_CONTACT_NO, STAFF_ADDRESS, STAFF_GENDER 
  FROM STAFF 
  WHERE DES_ID=101;
```

Comment: ```sql

SQL> ALTER VIEW TOURGUIDE ADD LICENSE_STATUS VARCHAR(10 CHAR);
ALTER VIEW TOURGUIDE ADD LICENSE_STATUS VARCHAR(10 CHAR)
                         *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00922: missing or invalid option
```
I need to add few more columns to the TOURGUIDE but when I alter I received this error. 

How can I alter the view to add columns?

Comment: I don't think the `ALTER VIEW` clause allows you to add/remove columns, but only to tweak other properties of the existing view. If you need to change columns, just drop the view, and create it again with the expanded `SELECT`.